# What is a necessary condition to form a set of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A collection of vectors is said to **span** the space if every vector can be written as a linear combination of the members of this set. A set of linearly independent vectors that span the space is called **basis**
How can a set of linearly independent vectors span the space if necessary condition of spanning is that *every vector can be written as the linear combination of the members* which makes it linearly dependent??

Comment: This is not a contradiction, it only means that the unique way to write an element $b$ of the basis is to write it as $b=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors from the basis are linearly independent. None of *them* is a linear combination of the *other* vectors from the basis.

The vectors from the basis span the whole space. Every *other* vector in the vector space is a linear combination of the vectors in the basis.

I don't see any contradiction here.

Comment: so, that means a set of linearly independent vectors **can** span the space??

Comment: Yes, they certainly can. I would also like to show you an example, but not sure which vector space is the closest to your mind. Take, for example, the vectors in geometry, in a plane. Pick any two non-zero and non-collinear vectors $v $ and $w $. They would make a basis. None of them is a linear combination of the other one, and every vector $u $ in the plane can be written as $u=\alpha v+\beta w $ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R $.

Comment: okay, got it .thanks

Answer (score 1):

Who said that in a linear combination of vectors of a set of vectors, all vectors in the set are actually  involved?

It is even necessary that all vectors of a spanning set do not appear in the linear combination in the case of an infinite dimensional vector space, such as the ring of polynomials $K[X]$ over a field $K$.

What the notion of *basis* adds to the notion of *spanning set* (or set of *generators*) is simply the fact that the linear combination that decomposes a given vector is *unique*.

Answer (score 0):

A set of $n$ vectors are a basis for a space or a subspace with dimension $n$ if and only if they are **linearly independent**.

Conversely if in a space or a subspace you can find at most $n$ vectors linearly independent we define $n$ the dimension of the space.